# arduino passing struct as argument to function

Tags: function, struct, arduino

I'm using an Arduino library for a radio.

[Arduino radio](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/extreme-range-lora-sx1272-module-shield-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo#step3_2)

If you do crtl+f and for "Transmission without ACK" you will see example code.

There is a function called sendPacketTimeout(). This function takes a destination and payload packet of type char, for example like this.

```
char message1 [] = "Hello";

void setup()
{

}
void loop(void)
{
e = sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, message1);
}
```

I've copied the sendPacketTimeout() function declaration from the header file below.

**Questions**

1. can you only pass a char to the function?
2. Could I create a struct with information and pass that to the function for example like this.

//

```
struct messagePacket {
char boardID[3];       
char temperature[3];
char humidity[3];
};

struct messagePacket myPacket;

void setup() {
struct messagePacket myPacket;
Serial.begin(9600);
strcpy(myPacket.boardID, "01");
strcpy(myPacket.temperature, "75");
strcpy(myPacket.humidity, "90"); 
e = sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, myPacket;
```

This the function declaration from the library

```
uint8_t sendPacketTimeout(uint8_t dest, char *payload);

//! It sends the packet wich payload is a parameter before ending MAX_TIMEOUT.
/*!
\param uint8_t dest : packet destination.
\param uint8_t *payload: packet payload.
\param uint16_t length : payload buffer length.
\return '0' on success, '1' otherwise
*/
uint8_t sendPacketTimeout(uint8_t dest, uint8_t *payload, uint16_t length);

//! It sends the packet wich payload is a parameter before ending 'wait' time.
/*!
\param uint8_t dest : packet destination.
\param char *payload : packet payload.
\param uint16_t wait : time to wait.
\return '0' on success, '1' otherwise
*/
```

Comment: You probably want: `sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, &myPacket, sizeof(myPacket));`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
struct messagePacket myPacket;
...
e = sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, (uint8_t*)&myPacket, sizeof(struct messagePacket));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a `struct messagePacket` as parameter because the function expects to be a `char*`.

To solve this, you can create your function and send the structure fields one by one, or you can concatenate them and send them all at once.

```
uint8_t sendPacketTimeout(uint8_t dest, struct messagePacket *myPacket);
{
    int e = 0;
    e = sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, myPacket->boardID);
    e += sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, myPacket->temperature);
    e += sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, myPacket->humidity);
    return e;
}
```

And you can send your struct now as parameter to this function.

```
struct messagePacket myPacket;
Serial.begin(9600);
strcpy(myPacket.boardID, "01");
strcpy(myPacket.temperature, "75");
strcpy(myPacket.humidity, "90"); 
e = sx1272.sendPacketTimeout(8, &myPacket);
```

Comment: Could I use the other function, like @Andrew and @leppie suggest?                                                              `uint8_t sendPacketTimeout(uint8_t dest, uint8_t *payload, uint16_t length)`  Apologies, very new to arduino and not quite sure what * & and unit mean and how to read them. thanks

Comment: @lucozade  To understand `*` and `&` you have to understand  **pointers** in C (or C++). That function refers to send an array `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` where this numbers are represend in 8 bits, and the length of the array which is `5` in my example.